# My lists are not displayed in the simulator but are well displayed in the preview

Tags: swiftui

I created a list with SwiftUI. My list is well displayed in the preview but not in the simulator:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var sandwiches: [Sandwich] = []
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(sandwiches) { item in
                NavigationLink(destination: Image(item.name)) {
                    Image(item.name)
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        Text(item.name)
                        Text("En Savoir plus...")
                            .font(.subheadline)
                            .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                    }
                }
            }.navigationBarTitle("Sandwiches")
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView(sandwiches: testData)
    }
}
```

[image]

Xcode version 11.5 (11E608c)

Answer (score 0):

In previews you create your `ContentView` like this:

```
ContentView(sandwiches: testData)
```

which assigns `testData` to your `sandwiches` property in the `ContentView`.

However, when running on the real device / simulator, your `ContentView` is usually created in the `SceneDelegate`.

Probably your `ContentView` in `SceneDelegate` is created like this:

```
ContentView()
```

It gives you no errors because you provided a default parameter for your `sandwiches` variable (and compiler allows you to skip it):

```
var sandwiches: [Sandwich] = []
```

If you create the `ContentView` like this:

```
class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?

    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {

        let contentView = ContentView() // <- here you need to pass `sandwiches`

        if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
            let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
            window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: contentView)
            self.window = window
            window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

you may want to pass the `sandwiches` parameter to the `ContentView` in the `SceneDelegate` as well (can be even your testData if it's available in the `SceneDelegate`):

```
ContentView(sandwiches: testData)
```